# How to show both date and time with datebox

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm using this datebox: http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox2/

```
<input name="txtHiddenCalendar" id="txtHiddenCalendar" type="date" data-role="datebox"  data-options='{ "themeHeader": "b", "zindex":1000, "mode": "calbox","themeDateToday" : "b", "themeDatePick" : "b"}' />
```

It displays only date part as: yyyy-mm-dd
How can I display the time along with this as: yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss

Answer (score 0):

you can try overrideDateFormat element.
i thik and hope this pattern solves your problem.

```
"overrideDateFormat" :"%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S",
```

put the code appropriate  position and be carefull for upper and lower case of letter.